# Visual studio adds lots of dll files when building project

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a project where I'm referencing different versions of dll-files, and using solution configurations to switch.

Since I've modified my .net project settings Visual Studio now includes all of these files in my build for debug_2019, debug_2020 but not for debug_2021 (same for release)!

```
System.AppContext.dll
System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
System.Collections.dll
System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll
System.Collections.Specialized.dll
System.ComponentModel.dll
System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll
System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll
System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll
System.Console.dll
System.Data.Common.dll
System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll
System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll
System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll
System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll
System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll
System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll
System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll
System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll
System.Drawing.Primitives.dll
System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll
System.Globalization.Calendars.dll
System.Globalization.dll
System.Globalization.Extensions.dll
System.IO.Compression.dll
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll
System.IO.dll
System.IO.FileSystem.dll
System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll
System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll
System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll
System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll
System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll
System.IO.Pipes.dll
System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll
System.Linq.dll
System.Linq.Expressions.dll
System.Linq.Parallel.dll
System.Linq.Queryable.dll
System.Net.Http.dll
System.Net.NameResolution.dll
System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll
System.Net.Ping.dll
System.Net.Primitives.dll
System.Net.Requests.dll
System.Net.Security.dll
System.Net.Sockets.dll
System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll
System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll
System.Net.WebSockets.dll
System.ObjectModel.dll
System.Reflection.dll
System.Reflection.Extensions.dll
System.Reflection.Primitives.dll
System.Resources.Reader.dll
System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll
System.Resources.Writer.dll
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll
System.Runtime.dll
System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
System.Runtime.Handles.dll
System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll
System.Runtime.Numerics.dll
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll
System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll
System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll
System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll
System.Security.Claims.dll
System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll
System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll
System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll
System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll
System.Security.Principal.dll
System.Security.SecureString.dll
System.Text.Encoding.dll
System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll
System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll
System.Threading.dll
System.Threading.Overlapped.dll
System.Threading.Tasks.dll
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll
System.Threading.Thread.dll
System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll
System.Threading.Timer.dll
System.ValueTuple.dll
System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll
System.Xml.XDocument.dll
System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll
System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll
System.Xml.XPath.dll
System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll
```

Here is my csproj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{E90702A3-F892-45F7-A2FF-F65D1D44E9A0}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Common</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Common</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug_2019'">v4.7</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug_2020'">v4.7</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug_2021'">v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release_2019'">v4.7</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release_2020'">v4.7</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release_2021'">v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug_2019|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Debug_2019\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;RVT2019</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release_2019|x64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Release_2019\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>RVT2019</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug_2020|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Debug_2020\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;RVT2020</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release_2020|x64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Release_2020\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>RVT2020</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug_2021|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Debug_2021\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;RVT2021</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release_2021|x64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Release_2021\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>RVT2021</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Caliburn.Micro.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8e5891231f2ed21f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Caliburn.Micro.Core.4.0.161-rc\lib\netstandard2.0\Caliburn.Micro.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Caliburn.Micro.Platform, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8e5891231f2ed21f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Caliburn.Micro.4.0.161-rc\lib\net461\Caliburn.Micro.Platform.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Caliburn.Micro.Platform.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8e5891231f2ed21f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Caliburn.Micro.4.0.161-rc\lib\net461\Caliburn.Micro.Platform.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.15.0.4795.1000\lib\net20\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll</HintPath>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf.1.1.19\lib\net45\Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=66aa232afad40158, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.3.1.0\lib\net45\Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="AdWindows" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug_2019'">
      <HintPath>..\References\2019\AdWindows.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="AdWindows" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug_2020'">
      <HintPath>..\References\2020\AdWindows.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="AdWindows" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug_2021'">
      <HintPath>..\References\2021\AdWindows.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="AdWindows" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release_2019'">
      <HintPath>..\References\2019\AdWindows.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="AdWindows" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release_2020'">
      <HintPath>..\References\2020\AdWindows.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="AdWindows" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release_2021'">
      <HintPath>..\References\2021\AdWindows.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPI" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug_2019'">
      <HintPath>..\References\2019\RevitAPI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPI" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug_2020'">
      <HintPath>..\References\2020\RevitAPI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPI" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug_2021'">
      <HintPath>..\References\2021\RevitAPI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPI" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release_2019'">
      <HintPath>..\References\2019\RevitAPI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPI" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release_2020'">
      <HintPath>..\References\2020\RevitAPI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPI" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release_2021'">
      <HintPath>..\References\2021\RevitAPI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPIUI" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug_2019'">
      <HintPath>..\References\2019\RevitAPIUI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPIUI" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug_2020'">
      <HintPath>..\References\2020\RevitAPIUI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPIUI" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug_2021'">
      <HintPath>..\References\2021\RevitAPIUI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPIUI" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release_2019'">
      <HintPath>..\References\2019\RevitAPIUI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPIUI" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release_2020'">
      <HintPath>..\References\2020\RevitAPIUI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPIUI" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release_2021'">
      <HintPath>..\References\2021\RevitAPIUI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Design" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
    <Reference Include="Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e4669d2f30244f4, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.4.0.2\lib\net40\Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

And my solution file:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.28803.156
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Common", "Common\Common.csproj", "{E90702A3-F892-45F7-A2FF-F65D1D44E9A0}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug_2019|x64 = Debug_2019|x64
        Debug_2020|x64 = Debug_2020|x64
        Debug_2021|x64 = Debug_2021|x64
        Release_2019|x64 = Release_2019|x64
        Release_2020|x64 = Release_2020|x64
        Release_2021|x64 = Release_2021|x64
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {E90702A3-F892-45F7-A2FF-F65D1D44E9A0}.Debug_2019|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {E90702A3-F892-45F7-A2FF-F65D1D44E9A0}.Debug_2019|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {E90702A3-F892-45F7-A2FF-F65D1D44E9A0}.Debug_2020|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {E90702A3-F892-45F7-A2FF-F65D1D44E9A0}.Debug_2020|x64.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {E90702A3-F892-45F7-A2FF-F65D1D44E9A0}.Debug_2021|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {E90702A3-F892-45F7-A2FF-F65D1D44E9A0}.Debug_2021|x64.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {E90702A3-F892-45F7-A2FF-F65D1D44E9A0}.Release_2019|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {E90702A3-F892-45F7-A2FF-F65D1D44E9A0}.Release_2019|x64.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {E90702A3-F892-45F7-A2FF-F65D1D44E9A0}.Release_2020|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {E90702A3-F892-45F7-A2FF-F65D1D44E9A0}.Release_2020|x64.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {E90702A3-F892-45F7-A2FF-F65D1D44E9A0}.Release_2021|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {E90702A3-F892-45F7-A2FF-F65D1D44E9A0}.Release_2021|x64.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {A8DEE5BD-EB0D-4472-B8E2-32C1B0F96223}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

I have no idea what I've changed to make this happen. Have anyone seen this before and know what is causing this behavior?

Comment: How is this list different from what you were expecting?

Comment: Chances are that you've included references to some (if not all) of these during your "messing around" and have some redundant usings/references.

Comment: Could you provide details of what "messing around" was ?

Comment: That's a good guess, but It's not. I have 10 System.X references, not 100.

Comment: I was adding confitions to my targetframework as well as some references

Comment: I have added my csproj and solution files

Comment: Happens when you have a dependency on a .NETStandard assembly, like Caliburn.Micro.Core.  They are the glue that forwards the standard types to the corresponding .NETFramework types.  Target at least 4.7.2 to avoid.  Might as well hack out the entire conditional targeting so only 4.8 remains.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, switching to 4.7.2 solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same mystery and upvoted the OP. @HansPassant answer is correct. Changing target Framework to 4.7.2 or 4.8 fixes the issue. Here is the official response from Microsoft:

https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/545

> We decided to close this as won't fix.
>
> We learned that the code path that tries to be smart about not
> injecting the facades is very prone to errors. We don't believe this
> makes the servicing bar because it's likely to regress other
> scenarios.